# how do you specify a class function to use typescript props interface

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I've just found out I can do:

```
interface Product {
  name: string,
  price: number,
  category: string,
  id: string,
  quantity: number
}

bagTotal = (products: Product[]) => {

}
```

which is useful but I have this. where bag is one of my props coming from my redux store

```
interface IBagProps {
  bag: {
    products: Product[]
  }
}
```

so in the parameters of the function I want to use the bag props from the `IBagProps` interface

how do I this?

I wanted to do something like this: `bagTotal = (products: IBagProps) => {`

but that looks like it's going to pass all the props through

Comment: `bagTotal = (products: Product[]) ...`?

Comment: @quirimmo what's the question sorry?

Comment: Why the function param cannot be a simple array of Product?

Comment: because products is an array in the bag object and bag comes from props. so I thought that it should have to live in the props interface?

Comment: @quirimmo does that make sense?

Answer (score 1):

You can access to the type of the `bag` member simply like this:

```
type BagsInfo = IBagProps['bag']
```

You can then refactor the `bagTotal` function to something similar to:

```
function bagTotal(bagsInfo: BagsInfo) {
  return bagsInfo.products.length
}
```

If your `bagTotal` function is directly "connected" to the `products` array you can retrieve the `Product` type with:

```
type Product = IBagProps['bags']['products'][number]
```

Comment: ok, I missed the point. I need more context info: how are you connecting `bagTotal` to `IBagProps`? Is it a redux selector? as a solution you can adapt the input argument: `const adapt = (fn: (products: Product[]) => number) => (bagProps: IBagProps) => fn(bagProps.bag.products)` and then when using `bagTotal` just wrap with `adapt(bagTotal)`

Comment: ok I'll try and explain better. I know I can do this: `bagTotal = (products: Product[])`. but I just wanted to get it from `IBagProps` because I thought it makes more sense to put it in the props seeing as it's from there?

Answer (score 1):

It's as simple as this:

```
const bagTotal = (products: IBagProps['bag']['products']) => {

}
```

But normally you just directly use `Product[]`.

UPD, if you probably mean that `IBagProps` is passed to your function and you have to pull `products` from there, then destructuring like this can be done:

```
const bagTotal = ({ bag: {products} }: IBagProps) => {
    products.map(p => p.name)
  }
```

Comment: that first way doesn't look correct though and I've not seen people use it like that. I understand I can just use `Product[]` but does that mean in my PropsInterface for this class that I should leave bag empty?

Comment: @RedBaron There is not much wrong with the first approach, however, as I said, normally you just use `Product[]`. Regarding your second question I didn't get it, sorry. I am not too familiar with react, hence with `PropsInterface` as well.

Answer (score 1):

You could leverage *lookup types*:

```
class Bag extends React.Component<IBagProps> {
  bagTotal = (products: IBagProps['bag']['products']) => {
    /* ... */
  }
}
```

but it is hardly the most elegant approach. If your method depends on `Product[]`, it is perfectly fine to say:

```
class Bag extends React.Component<IBagProps> {
  bagTotal = (products: Product[]) => {
    /* ... */
  }
}
```

Not only is it more readable, but it also doesn't depend on the shape of your props. If one day you decide to change their structure to, let's say:

```
interface IBagProps {
  products: Product[]
}
```

your method signature will not be affected — as it shouldn't be.